# Solve the following equation $x^x=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

Solve $x^x=x$. My attempt:
$$
x^x=x\\
x\log x=\log x \\
x\log x-\log x =0\\
\log x\times(x-1)=0\\
\text{Equate each factor equal to 0:}\\
[1]: (x-1)=0 \implies x=1\\
[2]: \log x =0 \implies x=1
$$

I've only found one solution, but there's also another $x=-1$. What am I missing in my work?

Comment: $\log$ is not defined on nonpositive $x$, so by taking it you are only able to select positive solutions.

Comment: Your solution is almost correct, but since you're using log function, which domain is $\ge 0$, you're cutting the branch with another solution

Comment: Does that mean it's necessary to use the absolute value, i.e. $\log |x|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re missing that the logarithm is only defined for positive arguments, so right in your first step, you’re implicitly assuming that $x>0$.

So you need to consider the cases $x<0$ and $x=0$ as well.

For $x<0$ you can multiply both sides by $-1$ first to obtain $(-x)^x = -x$ (because $-x^x = (-x)^x$, provided $x^x$ is even defined). Note that negative solutions are much more fragile, as $x^x$ isn’t well-defined for every $x$.

The case $x=0$ can be simply checked; as $0^0$ is usually defined to be $1$ or left undefined, it’s not a solution.